# How create a list colorSets, access them and delete them in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to list colorSet names in order to control how many of them I have on a given mesh. I can't seem to pass the right variable to the cmds.ls for it to recognize colorSet

I've read around and it seems like mostly cmds.ls is used for meshes but with correct attributes it can be used to list pretty much anything

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

colorList = cmds.ls('colorSet*', sl=True, long=True)
objects = cmds.ls( sl=True, long=True)

if len(objects) > 0:
    if len(colorList) > 0:
        cmds.delete(colorList)

    result=cmds.polyColorSet(cr=True, colorSet='colorSet') 
    result=cmds.polyColorSet(cr=True, colorSet='colorSet')
```

The code ends up ignoring my if statement and continues to create colorSets indefinitely. How do I make my code delete old ones before creating new ones?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to see if a given object has an existing colorSet, and if it does then delete it?

Comment: Exactly. I’m trying to create a list that would store those color sets. Then if an object already has more than one simply clear out that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cmds.listHistory` to get all the inputs from an object, then `cmds.ls` to filter that result to find any color sets:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

for obj in cmds.ls(sl=True):  # Loop through the selection.
    history = cmds.listHistory(obj)  # Get a list of the object's history nodes, which may include a color set.
    existing_color_sets = cmds.ls(history, type="createColorSet")  # Filter history nodes to only color sets.
    if existing_color_sets:  # If a color set exists, delete it.
        cmds.delete(existing_color_sets)

    cmds.polyColorSet(obj, cr=True, colorSet="colorSet")  # Create a new color set.
```

Comment: Ok so I messed around with it for a while and here is what happens. I don't think that history gets properly recorded into existing_color_sets If I just spawned and there are no sets existing then I get a warning saying that nothing can be selected which is how it's supposed to be. If Color sets already exist then the warning message doesn't show up so the code identifies them in the history list. Problem is it doesn't delete them. If I switch `cmds.delete(existing_color_sets)`  to `cmds.delete(object)` then it deletes the object as intended.  The code is deleting the history but not the sets

Comment: Wait! I got it. I cheesed my way around it. I know this is just a short term solution but I couldn't get it to delete the sets inside the history as whole so instead I told it to delete specific sets if they exist so: `if colorSets:
                cmds.polyColorSet(delete=True, colorSet='colorSet1')`

Answer (score 2):

You should also be able to get the color sets with

```
cmds.polyColorSet( your_object_here, q=True, acs=True )
```

To avoid extra `None` checks i'd try

```
def num_color_sets(obj):
    return len(cmds.polyColorSet( obj, q=True, acs=True ) or [])
```

This should work even if the actual colorSet nodes have been deleted by a delete history operation